# How to define a custom condition or permission for use in alfresco share global header?

Tags: alfresco-share

The following is an excerpt for the share global header:

```
<container-group id="tools" permission="admin">  <== Like this
                        <item type="link" id="application">/console/admin-console/application</item>
                        <item type="link" id="groups">/console/admin-console/groups</item>
                        <item type="link" id="replication-jobs" condition="!conditionEditionTeam">/console/admin-console/replication-jobs
                        </item>
                        <item type="link" id="repository">/console/admin-console/repository</item>
                        <item type="link" id="trashcan">/console/admin-console/trashcan</item>
                        <item type="link" id="users">/console/admin-console/users</item>
                        <item type="link" id="more">/console/admin-console/</item>
                    </container-group>
                </item>
            </app-items>
            <user-items>
                <item type="container" id="user" icon="" description="">
                    <container-group id="usermenu" label="">
                        <item type="user" id="status">{userprofilepage}</item>
                        <item type="link" id="my-profile">{userprofilepage}</item>
                        <item type="link" id="change-password" condition="user.capabilities.isMutable">/user/change-password
                        </item>
                        <item type="link" id="logout" condition="!context.externalAuthentication">/dologout</item> <== Or Like this
                    </container-group>
                </item>
```

I'd like to know how to define my own condition or how to leverage permission against an arbitral group for another set of menu items I want to add to it.
Is this possible?

Edit: 
I found this [share wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Share_Header#.22container.22_type) for 3.4 but not sure it's still relevant to my installation (4.2.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this solution is a little bit messy but at least it gets the job done. Maybe you can add the check-fct in something like "myOwnChecks.inc.ftl" if you need them in other places as well (at least I used them in several other places as well).

The js-controller in the webscript used (`header.get.*`) for the header component can be found at `../alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/header/header.get.js`.
Within the js-controller (`header.get.js`) is the function "getHeader()" where the variable "permissions" is set for the model. This is the only file you need to change, you can check out `header.inc.ftl` if you'd like to see how it's used to apply permissions.

```
/**
 * Customizable Header
 */
function getHeader()
{
  // Array of tokenised values for use in i18n messages
  model.labelTokens = [ user.name || "", user.firstName || "", user.lastName || "", user.fullName || ""];
  model.permissions =
  {
    guest: user.isGuest,
    admin: user.isAdmin
  };
}
```

Add the additional entries you'd later like to use in the share-conf (it's a simple share-webscript, remote-calls to alfresco are possible of course), f.e.

```
model.permissions =
{
  guest: user.isGuest,
  admin: user.isAdmin,
  adminGrp: isInAdminGrp()
};
```

And then a simple `permission="adminGrp"` in share-conf should suffice.